# How to compare data structures in clojure and highlight differences

Tags: testing, clojure

Is there a nice way to print out differences in clojure data structures? In Perl for example there is [Test::Differences](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Test-Differences-0.61/lib/Test/Differences.pm) which helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I really searched for was [difform](https://github.com/GeorgeJahad/difform). Using `clojure.data/diff` is nice but does not work well in a unit test where larger structures are compared. Here is an example where `data/diff` does not perform as well as difform in my opinion:

```
(defn example []
  (let [data [{:foo 1} {:value [{:bar 2}]}]]
    (diff data
          [{:value [{:bar 2}]}])

    (difform data
          [{:value [{:bar 2}]}])))

;; => diff output
;; => [[{:foo 1} {:value [{:bar 2}]}] [{:value [{:bar 2}]}] nil]

;; => difform output
   [{:
 - foo 1} {:
   value [{:bar 2}]}]
;; => nil
```

Comment: Sometimes output looks quite strange `(dfrm/difform #{1 2 3 4 555} #{1 2 3 4 555 5})` => 
`#{1 2 3 4 5+ 
5
   55}`

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at clojure.data/diff: http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.data-api.html#clojure.data/diff

Examples:

```
async-demo.core> (use 'clojure.data)
nil
async-demo.core> (diff {:a 2 :b 4} {:a 2})
({:b 4} nil {:a 2})
async-demo.core> (diff [1 2 3 4] [1 2 6 7])
[[nil nil 3 4] [nil nil 6 7] [1 2]]
async-demo.core> (diff #{"one" "two" "three"} #{"one" "fourty-four"})
[#{"two" "three"} #{"fourty-four"} #{"one"}]
```

Comment: `diff` is very cool. I think this would be a better answer if you add some more info besides the link, particularly an example or two.

Answer (score 4):

You can also visually diff two data structures using the [gui-diff](https://github.com/AlexBaranosky/gui-diff) library.

`(gui-diff {:a 1} {:a 2})` will shell out to an OS-appropriate gui diffing program to diff the two, potentially very large, data structures.

Comment: does not support Windows :(

Answer (score 2):

Fanciest diff what I saw is **[deep-diff](https://github.com/lambdaisland/deep-diff)**

It produces nice colorful diff like this

[image]

There also mention of nice **editscript** lib whick produce diff as array of patches.

Comment: Props for the Oolong teas. You should try Roasted TGY too.

Answer (score 1):

[Differ](https://github.com/ul/differ) is a recent library that seems to do a nice job:

```
(def person-map {:name "Robin"
                 :age 25
                 :sex :male
                 :phone {:home 99999999
                         :work 12121212})

(def person-diff (differ/diff person-map {:name "Robin Heggelund Hansen"
                                          :age 26
                                          :phone {:home 99999999})

;; person-diff will now be [{:name "Robin Heggelund Hansen"
;;                           :age 26}
;;                          {:sex 0
;;                           :phone {:work 0}]
```

EDITED: fix Differ repo URL that change from gitlab to GitHub

Comment: And it's gone. It seems that repository has been deleted.

Comment: And it seems like useless - "NOTE: Currently, only maps are supported."