# Clojure json comparing

Tags: json, clojure, clojure-java-interop

In some of my testing I am comparing json result between some http calls, today I am just comparing strings, which is too naive and not reliable for example if order changes.
Can you please recommend how to compare two json that may come in a different order of the elements like:

```
{
  "k1":"v1",
  "k2":"v2"
}
```

and

```
{
  "k2":"v2",
  "k1":"v1"
}
```

Thanks
Oded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586860/2596132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the JSON bodies to Clojure data structures with for example [`cheshire`](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) and compare those:

```clj
(ns my.ns
  (:require 
   [cheshire.core :as json]))

(def body1
  "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}")

(def body2
  "{\"b\": 2, \"a\": 1}")

(= body1 body2)
;; => false

(let [keywordize-keys? true]
  (= (json/decode body1 keywordize-keys?)
     (json/decode body2 keywordize-keys?)))
;; => true
```